# Is there Object.create equivalent for creating functions with __proto__ of my choice

Tags: javascript

Is there equivalent to `Object.create` for creating function with other functions in prototype chain similar to

```
var FF = {};
var A = Object.create(FF);
var a = Object.create(A);
```

So far I'm came up with this code:

```
function FF(){
    var instance = function(){
        return FF.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    instance.nextPrototype = instance;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, this.nextPrototype);
    return instance;
}
FF.nextPrototype = FF;
var A = new FF;
var B = new FF;
var a = new A

assert.notEqual(A, B);
assert.equal(A.nextPrototype, A);
assert.equal(B.nextPrototype, B);
assert.equal(A.__proto__, FF);
assert.equal(B.__proto__, FF);
assert.equal(a.__proto__, A);
```

But it is order of magnitude slower than `Object.create`, not to mention it modifies `__proto__` which is not so good practice.

Reason:
My only reason is to be able to have syntactic sugar of `new` operator e.g. to by able to do

```
var Human = magicMethod()
var Male  = new Human()
male.gender = 'male'
var john = new Male()
john.name = 'Doe'
```

Right now my code looks like this

```
var Human = {
    create: function() {
        Object.create(this)
    }
}
var Male  = Human.create()
male.gender = 'male'
var john = Male.create()
john.name = 'Doe'
```

Most editor and highlight `new` with different color so it is easier to see where I'm creating new objects.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is about `Object.create()` that doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: try bind() instead of hand-rolling the wrapper function

Comment: I'm trying to make code look clearer in editor by using `new` where ever I'm creating a new base objects for types

Comment: that's an even worse reason to write poor code than performance.

Comment: `Object.create()` was created to abstract away the implementation of creating a new object, calling the parent type's constructor, changing its prototype to a new instance and correcting the constructor on that new prototype instance. The need to use the `new` keyword is generally considered a bad thing in the language because it can easily be omitted by mistake causing bugs in the code.

Comment: Did you look into factory pattern? Check out this article for some interesting info: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e

Comment: By the way, you have to correct the `constructor` of the new object's prototype **after** setting the prototype, not before, because the `constructor` you've set will be lost when you change the prototype.

Comment: constructor property is set correctly, it just isn't constructor property in classic  sense

Comment: `instance.constructor = instance;` and `FF.constructor = FF;` are really weird. Not sure what's their purpose anyway (seems like you wanted an alternative to `Object.getPrototypeOf`), but the property should definitely not be named "constructor".

Comment: ok, I renamed `constructor` to `nextPrototype` to make it less confusing